# MacBook Pro - Flip front camera for documents online

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey, camera

Sometimes Apple just drive me up the wall. I need to show an identity document to a bank, so, of course (Apple!! OF COURSE) I need to flip the camera.

Is it easy? No. Are there lots of click bait solutions on the net. Yes.

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> System Preferences didn't do it for me. I'm on Monterey so there's no Camera in System Preferences.

How can I flip the camera?

Comment: This is up to applications to provide. For example, Teams has a "flip camera" toggle. macOS has no system level camera settings.

Comment: I have two MacBook Pro's - neither has two cameras - only one at the top middle of the screen. If I take an image of a document I can flip it using Preview.

Comment: Have you considered that only the view *you* get is mirrored? Even the simplistic Photo Booth turns the picture back round the right way once you take it. FaceTime too to the person at the other end.

Comment: Do you mean flip the camera *image*?  Why doesn’t an image from your phone work?  Are you showing this on a live video feed?

Comment: I interpreted this as a live video feed, probably in Safari or another browser, with the bank verification feed

Comment: @Tetsujin has it: YOUR video is shown mirrored, but the stream they receive should be the right way round.

Comment: @benwiggy no, the browser feed, which the verification process uses, is mirror image so the document is rejected. I guess a corollary is; is it possible in any browser to flip the feed?

Comment: @Ezekiel that’s correct

Answer (score 1):

It’s not going to be possible directly but, on the principle that you can always fool a computer, I will take a photo with a phone, flip it and then present that to the live feed. Or use a device with two cameras.

I am simply annoyed and frustrated that I’ve spent £3000 on a computer that won’t perform a simple operation that I require.

Comment: It's equally the responsibility of whoever wrote the web page, who ought to be aware devices often mirror & should know to be able to flip it themselves.